# Why do I get "Not a hexadecimal character" when using tdbloader2

Tags: java, unicode, rdf, jena

I'm loading a recent DBPedia dump file, specifically short_abstracts_en.nt available from http://data.dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/dbpedia/2014/en/short_abstracts_en.nt.bz2 (warning, 409M file). 
tdbloader2 fails to load, with:

```
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1263473, col: 122] Not a hexadecimal character:
```

I can replicate this error with riot --validate

```
$JENA_HOME/bin/riot --validate /var/data/uncompressed/short_abstracts_en.nt
20:04:36 ERROR riot                 :: [line: 1263473, col: 122] Not a hexadecimal character:
```

Line 1263473 of that file looks like this:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Taiwanese_kana> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> "Taiwanese kana (\u30BF\u30A \u30F2\u30A1\u30CC \u30AE\u30A \u30AB\u30A \u30D3\u30A7\u30F ) is a katakana-based writing system once used to write Holo Taiwanese, when Taiwan was ruled by Japan. It functioned as a phonetic guide to hanzi, much like furigana in Japanese or Zhuyin fuhao in Chinese. There were similar systems for other languages in Taiwan as well, including Hakka and Formosan languages.The system was imposed by Japan at the time, and used in a few dictionaries, as well as textbooks."@en .
```

Column 122 is part of the unicode set of characters: (\u30BF\u30A **\u30F2**\u30A1\u30CC \u30AE\u30A \u30AB\u30A \u30D3\u30A7\u30F ) (with column 122 in bold: **\u30F2**).

The error message is correct: \u30F2 is a (valid) unicode character, not a hexadecimal character.

Why does Jena think it should be hex, and what do I do about it?

Comment: Your problem is with these sequences: `\u30A \`, which contain a trailing space. You could substitute the correct sequence if you know what it is, but if your data is being delivered to you like this your best solution is to contact the providers and get them to fix it.

Comment: So the correct sequence should be something like \u30BF\u30A\u30F2\u30A1\u30CC\u30AE\u30A\u30AB\u30A\u30D3\u30A7\u30F  ?

Comment: Why is that? Aren't spaces valid unicode character separators?

Comment: Perhaps, but here you have three hex  characters and a space when you should have four hex characters

Comment: Thanks. Why should I have four hex characters? Given that it is freebase data, it would be useful if I could explain exactly why the data is wrong?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/#n-triples-grammar and in particular the definition of uchar: `UCHAR  ::=  '\u' HEX HEX HEX HEX | '\U' HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX`. "Unicode code points may also be expressed using an \uXXXX (U+0 to U+FFFF) or \UXXXXXXXX syntax (for U+10000 onwards) where X is a hexadecimal digit [0-9A-F]". As for 'why?', the parser need some way to know when an encoded character has finished: in this case it's just the length.